# How to keep parent li opened when i clicked the child li element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="entypo-tools"></i>
        <span class="title">PHP-SDK</span>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary">3</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="/mypage_v2/sdk/installation">
                <i class="entypo-inbox"></i>
                <span class="title">Installation</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="/mypage_v2/sdk/getStarted">
                <i class="entypo-docs"></i>
                <span class="title">Getting Started</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="entypo-flash"></i>
                <span class="title">API-Endpoints</span>
                <span class="badge badge-info">3</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="entypo-newspaper"></i>
                        <span class="title">sample1</span>
                        <span class="badge badge-success">4</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/mypage_v2/sdk/newsletter">
                                <i class="entypo-newspaper"></i>
                                <span class="title">sample1</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/mypage_v2/sdk/newsletterEmail">
                                <i class="entypo-newspaper"></i>
                                <span class="title">sample2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/mypage_v2/sdk/newsletteranalytics">
                                <i class="entypo-newspaper"></i>
                                <span class="title">sample2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/mypage_v2/sdk/sample2">
                                <i class="entypo-newspaper"></i>
                                <span class="title">NewslettersProcess</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Show your code and minimal example

Comment: What have you tried? Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Aq7iDsZc2BpvhkJlqD9AyMHb-MX0in7gVJifqgHr5rQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am ok with the condition of laravel routes

`<li @if(Request::path() == "mypage_v2/applications/lists" || Request::path() == "mypage_v2/applications/register") class="active opened")@endif>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use php rendering and on menu item click page refreshes, you can add class for example "active" to parent li(s), and in styles add `li.active {display:block}` or something like that style to show hidden elements

Comment: thank you.. i knew that... but current issue is when i clicked to child li tag the parent li automatically close.. i want it to still opened when i clicked to child... should i need to use some js?

Comment: yes i think, you should find click event in "dropdownmenu.js" file and change it.